# Where can I refill my water bottle at Doha (DOH) airport during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, qatar, doha, doh, environment

The typical water refilling stations near the restroom appear to be closed:

[image]

I don't know whether that's the case for all water refilling stations or just the one I saw, and whether there exist other solutions to refilling one's bottle without having to purchase a new water bottle.

Where can I refill my water bottle at Doha (DOH) airport during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Comment: In the bathroom?

Comment: @JonathanReez perhaps. Is that ok to drink?

Comment: Seeing you are there, have you asked at any convenient customer service desk?

Comment: @PeterM no~~~~~

Comment: Why not?  Airport staff are the ones with most up to date knowledge of their environment.

Comment: @PeterM I was working

Comment: Suggestion: don't, just take the hit and buy a new one.

Comment: Another trick, but not really an answer to the question asked, is to ask for a few water bottles on your arriving flight (an hour or so before landing). When you arrive in Doha, you can actually wait in the upper part of the airport (there's almost nobody there, but there are seats and toilets) before going through security where you will probably have to throw out your water. Then two hours before your next flight departs, you can slowly make your way through security and to the gate without getting too thirsty.

Comment: @JJJ thanks, yes good point! You're welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: [Why did this question regarding airport facilities get closed as a shopping question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6936/1810)

Comment: @JonathanReez Increasingly often, public toilets no longer provide cold and hot water but only warm water, which isn't great to drink.  In some parts of the world, it may also be (heavily) chlorinated.

Comment: @Glorfindel why do you think this is a shopping question? This is about airport facilities, which is on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1) perhaps the bathroom water is ok to drink 2) ask the helpdesk 3) Buy water.

> - In the bathroom? – [JonathanReez**♦**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) [yesterday](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162875/where-can-i-refill-my-water-bottle-at-doha-doh-airport-during-the-covid-19-pan#comment408288_162875)
> - Ask at any convenient customer service desk – [Peter M](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6188/peter-m) [yesterday](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162875/where-can-i-refill-my-water-bottle-at-doha-doh-airport-during-the-covid-19-pan#comment408290_162875)
> - Suggestion: don't, just take the hit and buy a new one. – [user253751](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29850/user253751) [Mar 15 at 18:01](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162875/where-can-i-refill-my-water-bottle-at-doha-doh-airport-during-the-covid-19-pan#comment408322_162875)